# Precondition failed: Negative count not allowed

Tags: swift, string, int, repeat, uint

**Error:**

`Precondition failed: Negative count not allowed: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.74.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/StringLegacy.swift, line 49`

**Code:**

`String(repeating: "a", count: -1)`

**Thinking:**

Well, it doesn't make sense repeating some string a negative number of times. Since we have types in Swift, why not use an `UInt`?

Here we have some documentation about it.

> Use UInt only when you specifically need an unsigned integer type with
>   the same size as the platform’s native word size. If this isn’t the
>   case, Int is preferred, even when the values to be stored are known to
>   be nonnegative. A consistent use of Int for integer values aids code
>   interoperability, avoids the need to convert between different number
>   types, and matches integer type inference, as described in Type Safety
>   and Type Inference.

*[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)*

Ok that `Int` is preferred, therefore the API is just following the rules, but why the Strings API is designed like that? Why this constructor is not private and the a public one with `UInt` ro something like that? Is there a "real" reason? It this some "undefined behavior" kind of thing?

Also: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/98594

Answer (score 1):

This isn't undefined behavior — in fact, a precondition indicates the exact opposite: an explicit check was made to ensure that the given `count` is positive.

As to why the parameter is an `Int` and not a `UInt` — this is a consequence of two decisions made early in the design of Swift:

1. Unlike C and Objective-C, Swift does not allow implicit (or even explicit) casting between integer types. You cannot pass an `Int` to function which takes a `UInt`, and vice versa, nor will the following cast succeed: `myInt as? UInt`. Swift's preferred method of converting is using initializers: `UInt(myInt)`
2. Since `Int`s are more generally applicable than `UInt`s, they would be the preferred integer type

As such, since converting between `Int`s and `UInt`s can be cumbersome and verbose, the easiest way to interoperate between the largest number of APIs is to write them all in terms of the common integer currency type: `Int`. As the docs you quote mention, this "aids code interoperability, avoids the need to convert between different number types, and matches integer type inference"; trapping at runtime on invalid input is a tradeoff of this decision.

In fact, `Int` is so strongly ingrained in Swift that when Apple framework interfaces are imported into Swift from Objective-C, `NSUInteger` parameters and return types are converted to `Int` and not `UInt`, for significantly easier interoperability.

Comment: Please, note that my question is more philosophical, since we have all this type safety thing going on in Swift and we can prevent this, why they delibetely created the constructor with `Int`? So Apple just didn't want to implement the `UInt` -> `Int` conversion, inside another `String` constructor with `count: UInt` for example, because they're be "backed" by those design decisions, even if this(and maybe other) API becomes "nonsense" since we don't have a negative number of repetitions? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It's not that the Swift devs didn't want to implement the `UInt` to `Int` conversion or couldn't have made the initializer to `String` take a `UInt` — it's that the result of such design leaves you, the consumer of the API, constantly casting between `Int` and `UInt` yourself, littering your code with `funcThatTakesInt(Int(resultOfSomeOtherFuncThatReturnsUInt))` and dealing with all of the potential issues there.

Comment: Note that some languages, like Java, don't have unsigned integer types at all, and they deal with this just fine. Swift provides unsigned types for C compatibility and for cases where you truly need the full range of an integer type, or to perform bit twiddling of sorts, but the lingua franca is signed integer types; in the efforts to not throw that burden on to you, almost all API takes `Int`.

Comment: Note also that this is done in an effort to avoid the implicit casting rules of C/Objective-C, which lead to a lot of real-world bugs. The only way out of implicit casting is explicit casting, which leaves you, well, explicitly casting everywhere, which is a big pain. This leaves edge cases like this one where, yes, an unsigned type would make more sense — but the pragmatism of writing it in terms of `Int` sometimes trumps the pedanticism of `UInt`. (I for one, tend to be pedantic, but there are always going to be API design decisions we disagree with.) :)